# SwiftUI TabView More tab crashes first press

Tags: swiftui, ios14, xcode12, tabview, tabitem

```
var body: some View {
        TabView {

            ScheduleView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
                Text("Schedule")
            }.tag(tbScheduleTag)
            DutyBookView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "books.vertical")
                Text(dutyBookViewTabText)
            }.tag(tbDutyBookTag)
            TimetableView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.clock")
                Text("Timetable")
            }.tag(tbTimetableTag)
            **... plus 7 other Tabs removed for post readability** 
         }
    }
```

My TabView creates 10 Tabs so I automatically get the "More" TabItem. After App launches and I press that More tab before anything else the Tab crashes back to the Initial tab. If I tap any other tab first or the More tab again it loads fine. See attached for demo. The first time selected it crashes back the second time it works.

Anyone suggestions please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `@State` variable and set it to `selection` attribute of `TabView`. To make this work I replaced your tags with new `enum` values.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    enum Tab {
        case schedule, dutyBook, timetable, locateTrain, settings
        case tfLRestricted, subscription, serviceStatus, info, storedDuties
    }
    
    @State var tab: Tab = .schedule
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: self.$tab) { //this is the solution
            ScheduleView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
                Text("Schedule")
            }.tag(Tab.schedule)
            
            DutyBookView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "books.vertical")
                Text(dutyBookViewTabText)
            }.tag(Tab.dutyBook)
            
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply adding the (selection: self.$tab) worked. I had omitted it as I thought id only need that if setting the selected tab programatically. Thanks @Pyry Lahtinen